# Cordova: Why do short videos work but not long videos?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video

I am testing my Cordova application on a Nexus 7.

I am using the HTML5 Video tag to display a video and my application needs to incorporate a video which lasts about an hour.

In my testing I can make short videos work but once videos reach a certain length there is an "Unable to load resource" error. However when I run the index.html in a web browser on my computer the long video works.

Is there a specific length of video that works in the video tag or does it depend on the device? And is there anything I can do to make the long video work?

I am using Javascript to program this.